# Find the sum of two lists of lists element-wise

Tags: python, list, nested, sum

I have two lists of lists, and I want to find the summation from two lists element-wise

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list2 = [[10, 2, 3], [11, 5, 6]]
```

Result should be `[11, 4, 6], [15, 10, 12]`
Currently, I have

```
for i in len(list1):
    sum = list1[i] + list2[i]
print(sum)
```

but it gives me wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `zip` like,

```
>>> list1
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> list2
[[10, 2, 3], [11, 5, 6]]
>>> [[x+y for x,y in zip(l1, l2)] for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2)]
[[11, 4, 6], [15, 10, 12]]
```

or if you are not sure, if both list will be of same length, then you can use `zip_longest` (`izip_longest` in python2) from `itertools` and use the `fillvalue` like,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> y = itertools.zip_longest([1,2], [3,4,5], fillvalue=0)
>>> list(y)
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (0, 5)]
```

that then you can use it for unequal sized data like,

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> list1=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> list2=[[10, 2, 3], [11, 5, 6], [1,2,3]]
>>> [[x+y for x,y in zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=0)] for l1,l2 in zip_longest(list1,list2, fillvalue=[])]
[[11, 4, 6], [15, 10, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it's rarely necessary to use indices, particularly for a task like this where you want to do the same thing to each element individually. The main function for that sort of transformation is [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), with list comprehensions offering a convenient shorthand. However, `map` does one thing those don't - process multiple iterables in parallel, like Haskell's [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith). We can break this down in two stages to do that:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list2 = [[10, 2, 3], [11, 5, 6]]
from operator import add
def addvectors(a, b):
    return list(map(add, a, b))
list3 = list(map(addvectors, list1, list2))
```

In Python 2, `map` returns a list, so you don't need to separately collect it as I've done with `list` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for that:

```
import numpy as np
list1=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list2=[[10, 2, 3], [11, 5, 6]]
list1_np = np.asarray(list1)
list2_np = np.asarray(list2)
total = list1_np + list2_np
print(total)
```

[[11  4  6]
 [15 10 12]]